# c++ analog for rust like synhronization

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

As I see on some video about rust, it have something
like this (I use c++ instead of rust to show idea):

```
template<typename T>
class Synchronized {
    public:
        Synchronized(T);
        Something<T> get();
    private:
        std::mutex lock_;
};
```

and usage like this:

```
Synchronized<std::string> obj;

auto s = obj.get();
//after that you can work with s as with std::string
//and obj.lock_ in locked state, after s was destroyed
//obj.lock_ will be unlocked
```

Is `boost` or some other C++ popular library have such pattern implementation?

Comment: Yes, Boost has an experimental class. Essentially it had an `operator*` that gives a reference to the contained object, with locking.

Comment: What's the name? @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: @sehe: I posted it as answer, it's here (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/sds.html#thread.sds.synchronized_valuesxxx). Sorry, I was away a little.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The as-of-this-writing experimental [`boost::synchronized_value`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/sds.html#thread.sds.synchronized_valuesxxx) appears to be what you're looking for.